# Audio normalization/fixation?

Tags: audio, fingerprint, waveform

I am using some audio fingerprinting technique to mark songs in long recordings. For example, in radio show records. Fingerprinting mechanism works fine but i have a problem with normalization (or downsampling).

[image]

Here you can see two same songs but different waveforms. I know i should make some DC Offset fixation and use some high and low gain filters. I already do them by Sox using highpass 1015 and lowpass 1015. And i use wavegain to fix the volume and DC Offset.  But in this case wave forms turns to one like below:

[image]

But even in this case, i can't get the same fingerprint. (I am not expecting %100 same but at least %50 would be good)

So. What do you think? What can i do to fix records to have same fingerprints? Maybe some audio filtering would work but i don't know which one to use? Can you help me?

By the way, here is the explanation of fingerprinting technique.

http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Future_Proof_Fingerprint

http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Future_Proof_Fingerprint_Function

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: Yeah, audio programming. But otherwise, is that "must" be "programming" question?

Answer (score 2):

Your input waveforms appear to be clipping, so no amount of filtering is going to result in a meaningful "fingerprint". Make sure you collect valid input samples that have a reasonable dynamic range but which do not clip.